# Ggplot Line Chart Manipulation

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I have the following data and want to plot several Line ggplots (each one representing the different stock1. Each plot would have multiple lines representing factor 1, 2, 3 etc (i.e. the 3rd to 6th column).

Data:

```
sample_data<-structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("2017-01-31", "2017-02-28", "2017-03-31", 
"2017-04-30"), class = "factor"), stock1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c"), class = "factor"), Factor1 = c(5, 6, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6), Factor2 = c(4, 4.5, 5, 4, 4.5, 6, 2, 3.4, 4, 5, 
4, 3), Factor3 = c(6, 7.8, 8, 8.5, 9, 8.5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5.5, 6
), Factor4 = c(5, 5.5, 6.2, 7, 5.5, 6, 3.4, 4, 5.6, 6, 7, 4)), .Names = c("Date", 
"stock1", "Factor1", "Factor2", "Factor3", "Factor4"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

So far I have tried:

```
ggplot(sample_data, aes(x=Date, y = [,3:6])) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~Stock1)
```

Comment: I suggest areas you want to brush up on are ggplot2 and the principles of tidy data. Your dates are factors, which will cause you issues and prevent you plotting what you think you should get from a plot.

A key issue is that it's not clear from your post whether your main struggle is with the syntax of ggplot or that your date factors are preventing you getting the lines you think you should get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making an assumption on quite how you want to present your data and suggest this will get you started:

```
library(tidyverse)
sample_data %>% 
mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% 
gather("Factor", "Value", 3:6) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Value, colour = Factor)) + 
geom_line() + 
facet_wrap(~stock1)
```

[image: Output line plot]